# Yii2 OpenID extension

Tags: yii2

I am getting back into Yii2 and have lost a bit of memory regarding the syntax surrounding using third party extensions.

I have a blank Yii2 application and am attempting to implement OpenID authentication for Steam, which I have done before but would like to do it cleanly now.

I am using [this](https://packagist.org/packages/vikas5914/steam-auth) extension and have put it in the Yii2 default loginform model. I realize this is wrong, and I should be defining a namespace of sorts. Just asking for clarification, thank you!

The error I'm receiving is 'Class 'app\models\Vikas5914\SteamAuth' not found' and I can't understand how to properly configure it.
Thank you!

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use vendor\Vikas5914\SteamAuth;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$config = array(
    'apikey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // Steam API KEY
    'domainname' => 'http://x.net', // Displayed domain in the login-screen
    'loginpage' => 'http://x.net/index.php?r=site/login', // Returns to last page if not set
    "logoutpage" => "",
    "skipAPI" => false, // true = dont get the data from steam, just return the steamid64
);

$steam = new Vikas5914\SteamAuth($config);

if ($steam->loggedIn()) {
    echo "Hello " . $steam->personaname . "!";
    echo "<a href='" . $steam->logout() . "'>Logout</a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href='" . $steam->loginUrl() . "'>Login</a>";
}

/**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the person who created that package.

You have used the wrong path in use method.

it should be `use Vikas5914\SteamAuth;`